# Get json array keys in android

Tags: android, json

```
{
    "204": {
        "host": "https:\/\/abc.com\/production-source\/ChangSha\/2013\/12\/02\/0\/0\/A\/Content\/",
        "timestamp": 1385909880,
        "cover": ["17\/Pg017.png",
        "18\/Pg018.png",
        "1\/Pg001.png",
        "2\/Pg002.png"],
        "year": "2013",
        "month": "12",
        "day": "02",
        "issue": "2013-12-02",
        "id": "204"
    },
    "203": {
        "host": "https:\/\/abc.com\/production-source\/ChangSha\/2013\/12\/01\/0\/0\/A\/Content\/",
        "timestamp": 1385806902,
        "cover": ["1\/Pg001.png",
        "2\/Pg002.png",
        "3\/Pg003.png",
        "4\/Pg004.png"],
        "year": "2013",
        "month": "12",
        "day": "01",
        "issue": "2013-12-01",
        "id": "203"
    },
    "202": {
        "host": "https:\/\/abc.com\/production-source\/ChangSha\/2013\/11\/30\/0\/0\/A\/Content\/",
        "timestamp": 1385720451,
        "cover": ["1\/Pg001.png",
        "2\/Pg002.png",
        "3\/Pg003.png",
        "4\/Pg004.png"],
        "year": "2013",
        "month": "11",
        "day": "30",
        "issue": "2013-11-30",
        "id": "202"
    }
}
```

The above sample json array , how to get the 204, 203 and 202? Thanks

I tried:

```
JSONArray issueArray = new JSONArray(jsonContent);

for (int j = 0; j < issueArray.length(); j++) {
    JSONObject issue = issueArray.getJSONObject(j);
    String _pubKey = issue.getString(0);
}
```

Comment: only key u want right dude..

Comment: This is not a json array,json array Start from "[" bracket not "{" this one,first format your array to valid json array & edit your question

Answer (score 33, accepted):

> above sample json array , how to get the 204, 203 and 202?

No, current String is `JSONObject` instead of `JSONArray`. you should get Iterator using [JSONObject. keys ()](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#keys%28%29) if inner JSONObject keys dynamic as:

```
JSONObject issueObj = new JSONObject(jsonContent);
Iterator iterator = issueObj.keys();
   while(iterator.hasNext()){
    String key = (String)iterator.next();
    JSONObject issue = issueObj.getJSONObject(key);

    //  get id from  issue
        String _pubKey = issue.optString("id");
    }
```

Comment: good answer, it shows how to get the values from nested json...

Answer (score 12):

Answer given by Mr. K is also right but you can also use **jsonObject names()** method. please find the sample code

```
for(int i = 0; i<jsonobject.length(); i++){
    Log.e(TAG, "Key = " + jsonobject.names().getString(i) + " value = " + jsonobject.get(jsonobject.names().getString(i)));
}
```

I hope dis will help you

Answer (score 11):

**User this method to iterate json dynamically**

```
private void parseJson(JSONObject data) {

        if (data != null) {
            Iterator<String> it = data.keys();
            while (it.hasNext()) {
                String key = it.next();

                try {
                    if (data.get(key) instanceof JSONArray) {
                        JSONArray arry = data.getJSONArray(key);
                        int size = arry.length();
                        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                            parseJson(arry.getJSONObject(i));
                        }
                    } else if (data.get(key) instanceof JSONObject) {
                        parseJson(data.getJSONObject(key));
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("" + key + " : " + data.optString(key));
                    }
                } catch (Throwable e) {
                    System.out.println("" + key + " : " + data.optString(key));
                    e.printStackTrace();

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `names()` as below to get the keys as `JSONArray` :

```
JSONArray jArray = jsonObject.names();
int len = jsonObject.length();
for (int i=0; i<len; i++) {
    String keyName = (String)jArray.get(i);
    JSONObject jValue = jsonObject.getJSONObject(keyName);
    String _pubKey = jValue.optString("id");
    //get the other values from jValue
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here you are trying to get `JSONArray` but in json response it is `JSONObject`.

Use following code.

```
JSONObject issueObject = new JSONObject(jsonContent);
String _pubKey = issueObject.getString(0);
```