# Get jsonarray key name

Tags: java, android, json

I need to get a key name of JsonArray, so JSON looks like this, please not, that JSON is starting with array brackets, and inside it it has objects, that was made i guess because back end will have the ability to add objects.

```
[
  {
    "tehnology": [ ]
  },
  {
    "science": []
  }
]
```

So i need to get the names from it "technology" and "science", because json can dynamically change, how can I implement it?

Comment: please put proper json string your json string is not proper the first brackets cant be square brackets. Check online json parsing sites

Comment: @Clairvoyant First brackets could be array brackets, jsonlint.com says my JSON is valid.

Comment: I think you should check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20321212/get-json-array-keys-in-android)

Comment: sorry its my bad square can be possible

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `JSONArray` contains `JSONObject`s. Retrieve every `JSONObject` and use `keys()` to access the key defined in every `JSONObject`

```
 JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(response);       
 for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
      JSONObject object = jArray.optJSONObject(i);
      Iterator<String> iterator = object.keys();
      while(iterator.hasNext()) {
        String currentKey = iterator.next();
      }
 }
```

Comment: how to do it by using GSON ?

Comment: @SundarG do you mean  in a custom deserializer ?

Comment: @Blackbelt Yes??