# How to create an array from JSON Key?

Tags: javascript, json

I get the json from API, and the json look's like :

```
"diagnosis": {
  "type": [],
  "kode": [],
  "PrimaryCat": [],
  "Location": [],
  "Encountrace": [],
  "Fracture": [],
  "Healing": [],
}
```

Expected Result:

I want to store the `keys` into array, and the result should be

> ['type', 'kode', 'PrimaryCat', 'Location', 'Encountrace', 'Fracture', 'Healing']

it is possible to get it?

Refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30412603/get-jsonarray-key-name), I cant convert the code from android into javascript

Comment: `var output = Object.keys(diagnosis)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `Object.keys` method.

> The Object.keys() method returns an array of a given object's own
>   enumerable properties, in the same order as that provided by a
>   for...in loop (the difference being that a for-in loop enumerates
>   properties in the prototype chain as well).

```
const keys = Object.keys(diagnosis)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Object.keys`. For more info see [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

```js
var diagnosis= {
  "type": [],
  "kode": [],
  "PrimaryCat": [],
  "Location": [],
  "Encountrace": [],
  "Fracture": [],
  "Healing": [],
}

var keys=Object.keys(diagnosis);
console.log(keys)
```