# How to parse the json objects having special characters in android

Tags: android, json, retrofit

I am new to android and I have the json in structure given below. How can it be parsed using json parsing or retrofit ?

```
{
   "1,abcd":[{
                 "v_id":"1"
               }]
   "2,efgh":[{
                 "v_id":"2"
               }]
}
```

Comment: Google's Gson library can do that for you out of the box.

Comment: What code have you tried to write? Share it please.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this**

```
try {
           JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject("yourresponce");
           JSONArray jsonarray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("1,abcd");


           for(int i=0;i<jsonarray.length();i++){
               JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
               String   v_id  = jsonObject1.getString("v_id");
               Log.d("seelogcat","values   "+v_id);

           }

           JSONArray jsonarray2 = jsonObject.getJSONArray("2,efgh");


           for(int i=0;i<jsonarray2.length();i++){
               JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonarray2.getJSONObject(i);
               String   v_id  = jsonObject1.getString("v_id");
               Log.d("seelogcat","values   "+v_id);

           }

       }catch (Exception e){

       }
```

Your json is Invalid Format:  your Format should be below like this

```
{
    "1,abcd": [{
        "v_id": "1"
    }],     // here you have to add (,)
    "2,efgh": [{
        "v_id": "2"
    }]
}
```

You can check here your Json is valid or not  https://jsonlint.com/

**To get key separate:**

```
Iterator<?> keys = response.keys();
while( keys.hasNext() ) {
    String key = (String)keys.next();
    if ( jObject.get(key) instanceof JSONObject ) {
        System.out.println(key); // here you need splint based on (,)
    }
}
```

Comment: The 1 in "1,abcd" is the id is it possible to separate them and used differently?

Comment: can you please explain how can we do that?

Comment: Is there other way to do so because the jsonfields are in large number? It will be very lengthy and confusing. @Gowthaman M

Comment: @Nbn what you want explain me clearly i will help you or i will give my suggestions

Comment: I have to get the id and the string name from jsonArrays for eg. from "1, abcd" where id is 1 and abcd the string value, I have to set the string value to the recycler view.But the problem is the JsonArrays are  in large number and dynamic and it becomes very lengthy and confusing to use the method you mentioned above.

Comment: @Nbn Ok look at this...you will get idea....https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20321212/get-json-array-keys-in-android

Answer (score 1):

You have a comma (,) missing there. Check in [jsonlint](https://jsonlint.com/)

```
{
    "1,abcd": [{
        "v_id": "1"
    }],
    "2,efgh": [{
        "v_id": "2"
    }]
}
```

Retrofit with Gson can do the rest of the work. The POJO for the response will be as follows:

```
public class Example {

@SerializedName("1,abcd")
@Expose
private List<_1Abcd> Abcd = null;
@SerializedName("2,efgh")
@Expose
private List<_2Efgh> Efgh = null;

public List<_1Abcd> get1Abcd() {
return Abcd;
}

public void set1Abcd(List<_1Abcd> Abcd) {
this.Abcd = Abcd;
}

public List<_2Efgh> get2Efgh() {
return Efgh;
}

public void set2Efgh(List<_2Efgh> Efgh) {
this.Efgh = Efgh;
}

}
```

And

```
public class _1Abcd {

@SerializedName("v_id")
@Expose
private String vId;

public String getVId() {
return vId;
}

public void setVId(String vId) {
this.vId = vId;
}

}
```

And

```
public class _2Efgh {

@SerializedName("v_id")
@Expose
private String vId;

public String getVId() {
return vId;
}

public void setVId(String vId) {
this.vId = vId;
}

}
```

Comment: What if we have large number of json objects? Do we have to "@SerializedName("jsonobjects")"and every objects presented?

Comment: You must use @SerializedName("YourJsonFieldName") with @Expose in order to get rid of silly runtime exceptions. go to this site http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ to get your POJO with a few clicks.

Comment: If my answer was helpful then plz upvote it. If you feel this is the solution then accept it as a solution. Happy Coding :-)

Comment: How can we handle the dyanamic JsonField? If the JsonField is added to the json do we have to Serialized the new jsonField or is there any other way to do so?

Comment: add all possible jsonfields to your POJO. if some value is returning null gson and retrofit automatically handle that. Serialization and deserialization is done automatically by gson.

Comment: you can accept my answer as solution if it served the pupose